# Add panel to the linked map in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to show the band compositions of sentinel-2 (i.e. 4 linked maps) in different years. However, can anyone give me a clue on how to add the panel of slider onto the split maps?

Here is the codes: https://code.earthengine.google.com/475585174fe8971bff87bb822ddc770c

---

The code is shown below:

```
// Display a grid of linked maps in different years

// A helper function to show the image for a given year on the default map.
var showLayer = function(year) {
Map.layers().reset();

year = ee.Number(year)

var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year,9,1);
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year,9,30);


// Create an initial mosiac, which we'll visualize in a few different ways.
var image = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate(startdate, enddate)
    // Scale the images to a smaller range, just for simpler visualization.
    .map(function f(e) { return e.divide(10000); })
    .median();

// Each map has a name and some visualization parameters.
var MAP_PARAMS = {
  'Natural Color (B4/B3/B2)': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  'Land/Water (B8/B11/B4)': ['B8', 'B11', 'B4'],
  'Color Infrared (B8/B4/B3)': ['B8', 'B4', 'B3'],
  'Vegetation (B12/B11/B4)': ['B12', 'B12', 'B4']
};

// Shared visualization parameters for the images.
function getVisualization(bands) {
  return {gamma: 1.3, min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: bands};
}


/*
 * Configure maps, link them in a grid
 */

// Create a map for each visualization option.
var maps = [];
Object.keys(MAP_PARAMS).forEach(function(name) {
  var map = ui.Map();
  map.add(ui.Label(name));
  map.addLayer(image, getVisualization(MAP_PARAMS[name]), name);
  map.setControlVisibility(false);
  maps.push(map);
});

var linker = ui.Map.Linker(maps);

// Enable zooming on the top-left map.
maps[0].setControlVisibility({zoomControl: true});

// Show the scale (e.g. '500m') on the bottom-right map.
maps[3].setControlVisibility({scaleControl: true});

// Create a grid of maps.
var mapGrid = ui.Panel(
    [
      ui.Panel([maps[0], maps[1]], null, {stretch: 'both'}),
      ui.Panel([maps[2], maps[3]], null, {stretch: 'both'})
    ],
    ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'), {stretch: 'both'});

// Center the map at an interesting spot in Greece. All
// other maps will align themselves to this parent map.
maps[0].setCenter(21.2712, 38.4151, 12);


/*
 * Add a title and initialize
 */

// Create a title.
var title = ui.Label('September 2018 Sentinel-2 Visualizations', {
  stretch: 'horizontal',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: '24px'
});

// Add the maps and title to the ui.root.
ui.root.widgets().reset([title, mapGrid]);
ui.root.setLayout(ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('vertical'));
}


// Create a label and slider.
var label = ui.Label('Select Year');
var slider = ui.Slider({
  min: 2016,
  max: 2019,
  step: 1,
  onChange: showLayer,
  style: {stretch: 'horizontal'}
});

// Create a panel that contains both the slider and the label.
var panel = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [label, slider],
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical'),
  style: {
    position: 'top-right',
    padding: '7px'
  }
});


print(panel)


// How to add panel to the Map (i.e. right after the title) ?? 
maps.add(panel)



// Set default values on the slider and map.
slider.setValue(2018);
```

Comment: Could you please add your code as part of the question, rather than an external link.  If the link becomes invalid, the code will stay here and help other people.

Comment: Sure! The code is shown below:

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the panel of the slider to the widgets' list

```
// Add the maps and title to the ui.root.
ui.root.widgets().reset([title, panel, mapGrid]);
ui.root.setLayout(ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('vertical'));
}
```